# How do I track down changed dependencies for Bugzilla?

Tags: package-management, bugzilla

I'm trying to install Bugzilla 5.0.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.  The Bugzilla [docs](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/installing/linux.html) state that I'll need the package 'libtemplate-perl-doc'.  This does not exist in the 20.04 repos.  A [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtemplate-perl-doc&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) shows that it existed for 16.04 but disappeared by 18.04.

I know that sometimes packages get absorbed into other packages or renamed.  I can't find any information on what happened to 'libtemplate-perl-doc' between 16.04 and 18.04, however.  How do I install whatever 'libtemplate-perl-doc' installed on 16.04 to make Bugzilla work on 20.04?

Comment: Why do you plan to use Bugzilla [release](https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla/releases/tag/release-5.0.4) from 2018 in 2020?

Comment: @N0rbert  I meant to type 5.0.6, sorry.  Slip of the finger.  Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install packages available for 20.04 LTS with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libappconfig-perl libdate-calc-perl build-essential libdatetime-timezone-perl libdatetime-perl libemail-sender-perl  libemail-mime-modifier-perl libdbi-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libcgi-pm-perl libmath-random-isaac-perl libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl  libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache2-mod-perl2-dev libchart-perl libxml-perl libxml-twig-perl perlmagick libgd-graph-perl libtemplate-plugin-gd-perl libsoap-lite-perl libhtml-scrubber-perl libjson-rpc-perl libdaemon-generic-perl libtheschwartz-perl libtest-taint-perl libauthen-radius-perl libfile-slurp-perl libencode-detect-perl libmodule-build-perl libnet-ldap-perl libauthen-sasl-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libhtml-formattext-withlinks-perl libgd-dev libmysqlclient-dev graphviz python3-sphinx
```

and then simply rely on Bugzilla's install script from bugzilla directory:

```
./checksetup.pl --check-modules
sudo ./install-module.pl --all
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Do you mind if I ask where you found that package list?

Comment: On the https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/installing/linux.html and then adapted it on fresh 20.04 LTS VM.

Comment: So, trial and error based on what's in the docs?  Seems to have worked, thanks!